# Constructing repeated measures ANOVA in R and extracting ls means.

Tags: r, anova, lsmeans

I am trying to properly construct a repeated measures ANOVA in R and extract the associated lsmeans. My data consists of a dependent variable (rSWC) and a predictor (Geno). The full dataset is as below:

```
> str(mydata)
'data.frame':   153 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Geno          : Factor w/ 5 levels "8306","8307",.. 
 $ BioRepeat     : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ Geno_BioRepeat: Factor w/ 17 levels "8306_1","8306_2",..
 $ Day           : Factor w/ 9 levels "1","2","3","4",.. 
 $ rSWC          : num  104.5 92.5 81.8 65.6 61 ...
```

I am constructing my repeated measures anova as:

```
rmaModel <- aov(rSWC ~ Geno + Error(Day/Geno), data=mydata)
```

I wish to extract the lsmeans (and associated variance terms) for Geno for every repeated measure (Day). At the moment if I try to extract the lsmean, I just get one lsmean for each Geno and a warning message that I cannot interpret:

```
> library(lsmeans)
> lsmeans(rmaModel, specs = "Geno")
 Geno      lsmean        SE    df lower.CL  upper.CL
 8306    59.43538  8.905658  8.00 38.89890  79.97187
 8307    58.06825  9.988820 12.45 35.03399  81.10251
 8417    71.16686 10.158125 13.24 47.74219  94.59154
 Control 86.97797 10.488538 14.84 62.79136 111.16459
 WT      45.76538  9.988820 12.45 22.73112  68.79964

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Warning message:
In lsm.basis.aovlist(object, trms, xlev, grid, ...) :
  Some predictors are correlated with the intercept - results are biased.
 May help to re-fit with different contrasts, e.g. 'contr.sum'
```

Any help to understand whether my model is constructed appropriately, how to extract the lsmean for each repeated measure, and how to interpret the warning message would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The default contrasts for statistical tests in R regression functions are treatment contrasts, so the "Intercept" level is generally the first of each of the factor variables. The warning message is suggesting you might redefine the contrasts for your Geno variable. So that might be done with:

```
 ?contrasts  # to get the background theory and example code
 contrasts(mydata$Geno) <- contr.sum(5) 
 rmaModel <- aov(rSWC ~ Geno + Error(Day/Geno), data=mydata) # refit
 lsmeans(rmaModel, specs = "Geno")
```

Comment: Thanks, that addressed the warning message. Any idea on how I can obtain the lsmeans for all repeated measures?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the problem. You should post a data example and indicate what part of the results are problematic.

Comment: My problem is that I would expect an lsmean value for each "geno" for each repeated measure (Day), but there is just a single lsmean for each "geno". I am wondering if the problem lies with not indicating that day is a repeated measure in the initial model or with my use of lsmeans()

Comment: Lsmeans only returns means for the fixed effects. The model you fitted has Day as a random effect. So if Day is actually an effect of interest, it should be in the models as a fixed effect, not part of the Error() term. Meanwhile I wonder if that other factor BioRepeat has any relevance and should somehow be included in the model. It might help to explain how you did the experiment and how you randomized it.